The format of data for text generation using LLM
I have a collection of poems in text data. I'd like to generate a new similar poem using LLM and fine tuning. How should I format the data for it?
If it's questions and answers, the data format should be:
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
...

But in my case, there is no prompt. only completions. The raw format I have now is:
[
  "poem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\n",
  "poem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\n",
  "poem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\npoem, poem, poem,\n",
...
]

I google "llm fine tuning text generation" but unfortunately no useful results were found.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Apply the Few-Shot Prompting technique: Give the LLM a few (you need to experiment with the exact number) of poems and use the same instruction for all of them:
{"prompt": "Write a poem", "completion": "<poem 1>"}
{"prompt": "Write a poem", "completion": "<poem 2>"}
{"prompt": "Write a poem", "completion": "<poem 3"}
...

To further improve the answers, it can be helpful to start the conversation with a system message specific to your needs.
